# How do i add an image to an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, element, hyperlink

I basically have this link, where when i click it, i want an image to show over it.  Using javascript how can i do this?

```
<a> click me </a>
```

css:

```
a.clicked
{
   /*what goes here?*/
}
```

Comment: You can't add an image over something using CSS.

Comment: gotcha.  but how can i add an element using javascript?

Comment: Oh. Ok. Yeah. You can do that. But adding a 'clicked' class to the link won't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a new image element is pretty easy:

```
// Append an image with source src to element
function appendImage(element, src, alt) {
  // DOM 0 method
  var image = new Image();

  // DOM 1+ - use this or above method
  // var image = document.createElement('img');

  // Set path and alt properties
  image.src = src;
  image.alt = alt;

  // Add it to the DOM
  element.appendChild(image);

  // If all went well, return false so navigation can 
  // be cancelled based on function outcome
  return false;
}
```

so in an A element:

```
<a onclick="appendImage(this, 'foo.jpg', 'Picture of foo');">Add an image</a>
```

If the A is a link and you wish to cancel navigation, return whatever the function returns. If the function doesn't return false, the link will be followed and should provide equivalent functionality:

```
<a href="link_to_picture or useful page" onclick="
  return appendImage(this, 'foo.jpg', 'Picture of foo');
">Add an image</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this. There are several other good methods, this is just for simplicity and understanding purpose

```
<body>
<a onClick='ChangeImage(this);return false'> Click Me <a>
</body>


<script>
function ChangeImage(obj)
{
 obj.innerHTML = "<img src='imangename.jpg'>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: how do you make the image stay there after user clicks on the link?

Comment: the image will stay, but it will overwrite when you click again.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript plugin you may need is Highslides, Check [here](http://highslide.com/#examples) for examples.

Download highslides [here](http://highslide.com/download.php).

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll probably want to give the link an ID.

```
<a id="click-me">Click me!</a>
```

Then for the JavaScript..

```
document.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "your-picture.jpeg/png/whatever";
    this.appendChild(image);
});
```

Comment: how do you make the image stay there after user clicks on the link?

Comment: It should stay there until they reload the page.